# SSRS: customize area bar chart (gantt chart) — different colors based on expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a dataset like on the picture, but there are more rows

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD7jb.png)

There I have employees names and their qualifications in my project, start date and end date of their vacations and vacations id.

Then i did an area bar chart (gantt chart) based on this dataset. Lines are grouped by vacation_id, start of line is vacation start date and end of line is vacation end date. The vertical axis shows the names of the workers, and the horizontal axis shows the dates of current month.
All lines are blue now. But I need to switch the lines color to red if vacations overlap by dates for those employees who have the same qualifications in my project.
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a way to identify the overlapping dates in the chart - you would need to add a field to indicate the overlap in the SQL.

If you put your current data in a temp table, then you could check for the overlapping:

```
SELECT 'A' EMP, '2019-11-08' START_VACA, '2019-11-13' END_VACA, 'QA' ROLE
INTO #VACA 
UNION
SELECT 'B' EMP, '2019-11-08' START_VACA, '2019-11-25' END_VACA, 'PM' ROLE
UNION
SELECT 'C' EMP, '2019-11-13' START_VACA, '2019-11-28' END_VACA, 'PM' ROLE
UNION
SELECT 'D' EMP, '2019-11-02' START_VACA, '2019-11-20' END_VACA, 'FD' ROLE
UNION
SELECT 'E' EMP, '2019-11-10' START_VACA, '2019-11-13' END_VACA, 'QA' ROLE

SELECT V.*, CASE WHEN V1.EMP IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OVERLAP
FROM #VACA V
LEFT JOIN #VACA V1 ON V1.ROLE = V.ROLE AND V1.EMP <> V.EMP
                    AND (
                        V1.START_VACA BETWEEN V.START_VACA AND V.END_VACA
                        OR
                        V1.END_VACA BETWEEN V.START_VACA AND V.END_VACA
                        OR
                        V.START_VACA BETWEEN V1.START_VACA AND V1.END_VACA
                        OR
                        V.END_VACA BETWEEN V1.START_VACA AND V1.END_VACA
                        )
```

[image]

Once you have an indicator for overlapping records, you can create an expression for the Chart Series' color.

```
=IIF(Fields!.OVERLAP.Value = 1, "RED", "BLUE")
```